# Trying to prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{1} \delta(x) \, dx = 1$

Tags: measure-theory, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

The definition of dirac delta distribution is that it is a distribution with the property:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x - k)f(x) {\rm d}x = f(k)$$

So if one takes the case $k = 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ then we get the heuristic

$$\delta(x) = \begin{cases} +\infty, & x = 0 \\ 0, & x \ne 0
\end{cases}$$ and satisfies the identity
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) \, dx = 1$$
We have
\begin{eqnarray}\int_{-\infty}^{1} \delta(x) \, dx &=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) \, dx - \int_{1}^{\infty} \delta(x) \, dx \\
&=& 1 - 0.
\end{eqnarray}
I suspect that this is not a correct way to prove this.

Comment: All is correct, albeit skipping some steps and adding unnecessary ones. Reduce all those integral to the defining property. $\int_{-\infty}^1\delta=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\chi_{(-\infty,1]}=\chi_{(-\infty,1]}(0)=1$. Also $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta=1|_{x=0}=1$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty}\delta=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\chi_{(1,\infty)}=\chi_{(1,\infty)}(0)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a rigorous proof, you may use the definition of distributions using functional analysis but I suggest this more straight forward argument: let
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,\ x<1\\0,\ x\ge1\end{cases}$$
then
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)f(x)dx=f(0)=1=\int_{-\infty}^1\delta(x)dx.$$